# May I say something 'has long been fascinating to me'?

Tags: grammar

Is it gramatically correct to say something like

> Basketball has long been fascinating to me

or is there a better alternative expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basketbal has long been fascinating (adjective) to me.

The sentence is OK.

You can also say as follows:

Basketball has been fascinating (adjective) to me for a long time.

Basketball has long fascinated me.

Basketball has fascinated me for a long time.

Basketball has long been a fascination for me.

Comment: When I say 'Basketball has long fascinated me', am I implying that I am no longer interested in it?

Comment: It implies it fascinated you in the past and it still fascinates you  in the present just as you say I have long lived in London.

Answer (score 4):

While you would be understood, you may benifite from saying:

> I have always been fascinated by Basketball.

Which is my personal preference, but you could also say

> Basketball has always been fascinating to me.

Or

> For as long as I can remember, basketball has always fascinated me.

Comment: *...has long fascinated me* is also acceptable. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+long+fascinated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20long%20fascinated%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Although not choosing your answer, I really appreciate your help. Many thank!